# jQuery ToggleClass on multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to toggle visibility of elements with jQuery. The page should load with all elements active. Then, when you click on one of 3 filter buttons, it should hide the elements that don't match.

I can get it to work with addClass and removeClass, but I want to be able to **toggle** the elements on and off when you click each button. This is where it falls apart. With toggleClass, it works on the first click, but when I try to toggle the buttons, the classes get all mixed up.

Here is a [**working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/lsterling03/3r4ey8ah/) using removeClass (no toggling):

```
$(".map-filters .heart").click(function() {
  $('.blue-marker').addClass('d-none');
  $('.green-marker').addClass('d-none');
  $('.red-marker').removeClass('d-none');
});
```

And here is a [**non-working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/lsterling03/3r4ey8ah/3/) where I attempt to toggle the classes –– once you click around a bit, it gets mixed up:

```
$(".map-filters .heart").click(function() {
  $('.blue-marker').addClass('d-none');
  $('.green-marker').addClass('d-none');
  $('.red-marker').toggleClass('d-none');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You have set the default to active to all of them.

2.You have to do make the decision based on the active not active of the button with `hasClass()`

3. You don't need code redundancy. You can simplify it by giving each button an id.

```js
$(".map-filters .filter").click(function() {
$('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
    var color = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#map").children().addClass('d-none');
    $("." + color + "-marker").toggleClass('d-none');
  }
  else {
   $("#map").children().removeClass('d-none');
  }
});
```

```css
.d-none {
  visibility:hidden!important
}
#map {
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:20px;
}
#map > div {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
   display:inline-block;
   margin:10px;
}
.map-filters {
  margin-top:50px;
}

.map-filters button {
  opacity:0.5;
}
.map-filters button.active {
  opacity:1;
}

.heart,
.red-marker {background:red;}

.heart-pvl,
.green-marker {background:green;}

.pvl,
.blue-marker {background:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map">
 <div class="blue-marker"></div>
  <div class="red-marker"></div>
  <div class="red-marker"></div>
  <div class="green-marker"></div>
  <div class="blue-marker"></div>
  <div class="green-marker"></div>
</div>

<div class="map-filters">
 <button type="button" class="filter heart" id="red">Heart Locations</button>
 <button type="button" class="filter heart-pvl" id="green">Heart & PVL Locations</button>
 <button type="button" class="filter pvl" id="blue">PVL  Locations</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure I can simplify the jquery as much as you have, as the real map html is more complicated (each marker element has its own ID and does not share a class -- I just simplified it for this question.) But this works with my provided code, so I'm trying to apply it to my real code to see if I can get there. Thanks!